# Prolog Predicate for positive and negative integers

Tags: prolog

I'm currently studying for an exam in Prolog and so am trying to do some sample questions to get ready. I've been trying this one for while, the task it to create intgr/1 so that

```
?-intgr(X).
X=0;
X=1;
X=-1;
X=2;
X=-2;
...
```

What I have now is

```
intgr(0).
intgr(X) :- intgr(Y), (X is Y + 1 ; X is Y - 1).
```

However, it lists them out in a really weird way, namely:

```
X = 0
X = 1
X = -1
X = 2
X = 0
X = 0
X = -2
X = 3 ...
```

I'm just wondering what a good approach would be to change that in order to get them listed out in the right order.

Comment: I don't understand the pattern, have you got a typo here? Should `X=2; X=2` really be `X=2; X=-2` ?  (And `X is Y - 1` be `X is 0 - Y`) ?

Comment: Sorry changed the pattern now thank you! And no I had  X is Y - 1 so you can go up or down from 0, but would 0-Y work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficient:

```
intgr(I) :-
    integer(I),
    % Any integer will do, can stop here
    !.
intgr(I) :-
    var(I),
    (   I = 0
    % Start alternating +/- with 1
    ;   intgr_(1, I)
    ).

% Plus
intgr_(N, N).
% Minus
intgr_(N, I) :-
    % Calc negative, rather than -(N) term
    I is -N.
intgr_(N, I) :-
    % Increment into infinity
    N1 is N + 1,
    intgr_(N1, I).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- intgr(-5).
true.

?- intgr(0).
true.

?- intgr(4).
true.

?- intgr(fish).
false. % Fails quickly, as appropriate

?- intgr(I).
?- intgr(I).
I = 0 ;
I = 1 ;
I = -1 ;
I = 2 ;
I = -2 ;
I = 3 ;
I = -3 ;
...
```

As @TA_intern pointed out, this can be shortened (if `inf` is supported in `between`) to:

```
intgr_between(I) :-
    integer(I),
    % Any integer will do, can stop here
    !.
intgr_between(I) :-
    var(I),
    (   I = 0
    % Start alternating +/- with 1
    ;   between(1, inf, N),
        (   I = N
        ;   I is -N
        )
    ).
```

Counting up to infinity can be implemented as e.g.:

```
incrementing_from(Start, N) :-
    integer(N),
    !,
    integer(Start),
    % Both variables are integer
    N @>= Start.
incrementing_from(Start, N) :-
    var(N),
    integer(Start),
    incrementing_from_(Start, N).

incrementing_from_(N, N).
incrementing_from_(U, N) :-
    U1 is U + 1,
    incrementing_from_(U1, N).
```